# directly copying from `vim` to `mariadb` shell causing error

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, neovim, gvim

I have a file https://0x0.st/oYoB.com_5zfu

After opening it with `vim` I tried to copy some portion of code and paste it in the `mariadb` shell. But it looked like `mariadb` was giving error.

```
MariaDB [The_Office]> create table `employees` (
    ->     employee_id char(10) not null,
    ->     first_name varchar(20) not null,
    ->     last_name varchar(20) not null,
    ->     email varchar(60) not null,
    ->     phone_number char(14) not null,
    ->     hire_date date not null,
    ->     job_id int not null,
    ->     salary varchar(30) not null,
    ->     comission_pct char(10) not null,
    ->     manager_id char(10) not null,
    ->     department_id char(10) not null
    -> );
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'create table `employees` (
    employee_id char(10) not null,
    first_na...' at line 1
MariaDB [The_Office]>
```

First I thought there is syntax error. After finding for a while I had no clue where is that syntax error. So, I used `cat` command and tried to directly copy from the terminal without opening in vim and this time `mariadb` shell worked flawlessly.

My `vim` copy keybinding is like this

```
vmap <C-C> :w !xclip -i -sel c<CR><CR>
```

I am still wondering what is wrong here?

Comment: Did you inspect the content of your clipboard?

Comment: It looks like `vi` has **Syntax Highlighting** which highlights `not` or `null` or both. This is generally with ASCII terminal Codes. This is getting copied to the clipboard due to your terminal settings. Eg If you Paste that into Word Processors , you will get that highlighting. Now , when you Paste that into `MariaDB` , those Escape codes are giving the Syntax Issue. When using `cat` , the highlighting is not there , hence Paste is normal , hence `MariaDB` is happy too !